# What is the difference between a warg and a skinchanger?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

Many times both terms are used as synonyms.

In A Storm of Swords, Jon mentions that he sees skinchangers ***and*** wargs among the wildlings.

George R.R. Martin, when asked about the difference said:

> A warg is bound to a wolf. Skinchanger is a more general term. All
>   wargs are skinchangers, but not all skinchangers are wargs.

But in the books sometimes are used the term *warg* to refer a skinchanger that controls other animals (such a hawk and a shadowcat by one of Mance's guards).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think "*Warg*" is just a synonym or subgroup to "*skinchanger*" in this case. GRRM is infamous for allowing his characters to use their own perspective on things, in which case they can use a term incorrectly. I think the term "*Warg*" is most often used in a superstitious fashion, and "*skinchanger*" more matter-of-factly.

Warg is also not GRRM's word, but something that's been around a while, read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warg).

Answer (score 10):

GRRM is correct that only a person who is able to enter minds of Wolves or Dogs [is called a warg](http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/World_Fantasy_Con_Saratoga_NY_November_1_4_2007). I do not see how do the examples you cite contradict it.

The Hawk belonged to a "Skinchanger" by the name [Orell](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Orell). Jon Snow kills Orell.

Later [Varamyr Sixskins](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Varamyr) claims the Hawk. And he uses it to scout against the Night's Watch at [Battle of Castle Black](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_of_Castle_Black) and before.

Varamyr is the "guard of Mance" that you are mentioning. He is correctly described as a warg because he does have Wolves bound to him. Following Animals were controlled by Varamyr:

1. A snow bear
2. A shadow Cat
3. A Hawk
4. **Three wolves** named [One-Eye](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/One_Eye), [Stalker](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Stalker) and [Sly](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Sly).

These are the six Skins of Varamyr. And since three of them are wolves, that makes Varamyr a warg, not just a skinchanger.

Depiction of Varamyr with his bear, shadow cat, hawk and wolves by [Elena Maria Vacas](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/rzDvO):

[image]

Wolves are special sort of Animals because from ADWD prologue:

> Wolves were harder. A man might befriend a wolf, even break a wolf,
>   but no man could truly tame a wolf. “Wolves and women wed for life,”
>   Haggon often said. “You take one, that’s a marriage. The wolf is part
>   of you from that day on, and you’re part of him. Both of you will
>   change.”

If you have any other examples of a Skinchanger without a wolf being called a warg, please share them. I do believe Varamyr is the only example here and you are mistaken about him.

**TLDR: As GRRM said, All Wargs are Skin-changers but not all Skin-changers are Wargs.**

Answer (score 1):

A Warg seems to be someone who can spirit-walk, or take over the senses or mind of another animal, while a Skinchanger just seems to be anyone who can change into or take over the body of an animal. So, Wargs are a type of Skinchanger. Wargs seem to be Greenseers as well, so they have premonitions in dreams. They also usually only spirit-walk into one or two kinds of animal.